# "'System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FullPath' is inaccessible due to its protection level" error in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# programme like as follows. But it fails. 
Error is 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FullPath' is inaccessible due to its protection level.
And FullPath underlined in blue.

```
protected void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryInfo parent = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\dell\Desktop\rename");
    foreach (DirectoryInfo child in parent.GetDirectories())
    {
        string newName = child.FullPath.Replace('_', '-');

        if (newName != child.FullPath)
        {
            child.MoveTo(newName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use FullName, not FullPath. FullPath is a protected field, it's not designed to be used this way. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx for explanation of access modifiers. And for fields/properties of FileSystemInfo refer to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I changed it to FullName and I replaced "public static" to "protected". It works now. I am closing this question. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can always see if the field is protected, private ect. by pressing F12.  // Summary:
    //     Provides the base class for both System.IO.FileInfo and System.IO.DirectoryInfo
    //     objects.
    [Serializable]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public abstract class FileSystemInfo : MarshalByRefObject, ISerializable
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the fully qualified path of the directory or file.
        protected string FullPath;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property that you are looking for is called [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx), not `FullPath`:

```
static void Main()
{
    DirectoryInfo parent = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\dell\Desktop\rename");
    foreach (DirectoryInfo child in parent.GetDirectories())
    {
        string newName = child.FullName.Replace('_', '-');

        if (newName != child.FullName)
        {
            child.MoveTo(newName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try FullName instead of FullPath:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/8s2fzb02.aspx

this should work for you :)